# Lesson plan title

Tags: word-usage

I'm a school teacher. Nowadays, classroom lesson is perceived as a session where students learn and teachers facilitate them in the learning process.

I need your help to decide which title is better for my daily lesson plan.

Daily Learning and Facilitation Record
or

Daily Learning and Facilitating Record
If there is any other way to put this, it is most welcome.

FYI, its the policy of the school where I teach that we ought to emphasize the concept of facilitation in classroom in order to avoid teacher centered teaching style. That means I need to include the term based on the word *facilitate* in the title

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facilitation of Daily Learning Report?  It all sounds like education-speak to me. It's only a title. What are the other educators using? In our school board -- they told us what reports were called.

Comment: Before this we only used daily lesson plan, until the department decided to emphasise the concept of facilitation i our system.

Answer (score 2):

I think

> Daily Learning and Facilitation Record

sounds best. Which would expand to

> Daily Learning and *Daily* Facilitation Record
>
> [**facilitation** - is any activity that makes tasks for others easy, or tasks that are assisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facilitation)

and since you are trying to keep a record of progress it would be

> a [facilitation record](http://www2.humboldt.edu/aof/)

Comment: I'm not a native speaker of the English Language, in fact both the titles mentioned above are translated from my native language. That is why I need inputs from native speakers to decide which one sounds more natural.

Comment: @Ibnu Abi The word input (and output) like information never takes an s. :) (except in certain production/manufacturing situations)

Answer (score 1):

**Daily Teaching Plan Focused on Facilitating Student Learning**

**Daily Teaching and Student Facilitating Plan**

Fanciest: :)

**Student-Facilitated Learning and Daily Teaching Plan***

Those are some ideas. Nothing is written in stone.

Teachers have teaching plans. They don't have records, per se. The school keeps records of many things. We speak of school records (of students).

Also, you teach and, it is hoped, the students learn. That's why I would use teaching instead of learning. Unless you give them a quiz every day and keep a record of their grades.

[quick reminder: when writing about a subject in general, the standard way to express that is: Classroom lessons are perceived to be x; A classroom lesson is perceived to be x;]

PS: Keep up the good work! [I have only taught adults and even found that to be trying (difficult).]